# After merging branch Y into X, three versions of the file created: fetch(X), merge(X) and X

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to merge the `master` branch into the `original` branch.  They are diverging branches.

I simply run

```
git checkout original
git merge master
```

and this resulted in many conflicts as I expected.

I opened one of the files containing conflicts and when I run `git diff` for this file (using `vim-fugitive`), three splits appeared; one called `fetch(original)`, one called `original`, and the third is called `merge(original)`.

I don't understand why there are three versions for `git diff` or what they really are. I couldn't find them in git branches or logs. How should I use them to solve the conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three versions, because you are doing a 3-way merge. They are the base, the local version and the remote version. Standard git terminology is *base*, *ours* and *theirs*; you can also get them with the `:1:`*filaname*, `:2:`*filename* and `:3:`*filename* blob references.

Actually, there are four: There is also the work tree file where the merge result goes. A *diff* operation would show you the merge result and the two sides of the merge, local (stage 2) and remote (stage 3).

Your goal with the 3-way merge algorithm is to combine the changes between base and ours with changes between base and theirs. The `git mergetool` command is there to help you. I recommend using [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose (i.e. install it, configure git to use it and then `git mergetool` will start it as appropriate).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you please tell me in which one should the conflictions marks (i.e., `<<<<<`') appear? This file should be the one that I should edit to solve the conflicts, right. In my case, these marks only appear in `original` version of file. Last point, I only have local repo (i.e., I only add and commit and don't push to a remote), in this case what should be the remote version?

Comment: @Salahuddin, actually, a *diff* will be showing work-tree—which is where the conflict marks are—against stage 2 (ours) and stage 3 (theirs). Since it's not showing stage 1, it is useless for merging. Use a merge toool instead.